# How to push new view from TableViewCell?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, pushviewcontroller, xcode4.6

In my app I am trying to navigate to a new View from a TableViewCell, But i dont know how. Could you help guys? I am using Xcode 4.6. and .xib, no storyboard. I am very new to coding so please explain it as simple as possible! Here is what i have tried, please correct me:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
tableData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"aaoversikt1", @"Paul", @"George", @"Ringo", nil];
[super viewDidLoad];
UILabel *nav_title1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 10, 220, 25)];
nav_title1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:18];
nav_title1.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
nav_title1.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
nav_title1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
nav_title1.text = @"Ålesund";
nav_title1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.navigationItem.titleView = nav_title1;
}

#pragma mark - TableView Data Source methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:        (NSInteger)section;
{
return [tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}

#pragma mark - TableView Delegate methods

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
AAOversiktViewController *aaoversikt1 = [[AAOversiktViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AAOversiktViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:aaoversikt1 animated:YES];
}
```

Thank You!

Comment: It looks like you've implemented didSelecdtRowAtIndexPath: correctly.  What problem are you seeing?  Note that after creating aaoversikt1 you would normally configure it with information about the selected cell.

Answer (score 0):

From first glance I would say that the problem lies within your [self.navigationController pushViewController] method. Have you initiated a navigation controller in your app either in the app delegate or root view controller?

If not i would recommend:

```
 [self presentViewController:aaoversik1 animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

If you are wanting to push through the navigation stack so that you have a back button then I would look at implementing a UINaviationController.

Otherwise you can create a custom back button and use the same method in this post to present the root view controller (not totally recomended as using UINavigationController is much cleaner).

Let me know if this has been of any help, T